# High JVM long pause in ignite client microservice

Tags: ignite

A high JVM long pause is coming in ignite thick client , resulting in client going out of cluster.

[2022:02:17:19:02:15] [org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal] [WARN] Possible too long JVM pause: 28690 milliseconds.
[2022:02:17:19:02:15] [org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi] [INFO] Client node disconnected from cluster, will try to reconnect with new id

There are no issues reported in the gc logs during the time of issue and also ignite client logs logs is also showing no high memory and cpu usage during the time of issue.

```
[2022:02:17:19:00:56] [org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal] [INFO] 
Metrics for local node (to disable set 'metricsLogFrequency' to 0)
    ^-- Node [id=35a3b804, uptime=4 days, 09:08:44.781]
    ^-- H/N/C [hosts=9, nodes=62, CPUs=120]
    ^-- CPU [cur=0.3%, avg=0.77%, GC=0%]
    ^-- PageMemory [pages=0]
    ^-- Heap [used=3958MB, free=35.58%, comm=6144MB]
    ^-- Off-heap [used=0MB, free=-1%, comm=0MB]
    ^-- Outbound messages queue [size=0]
    ^-- Public thread pool [active=0, idle=0, qSize=0]
    ^-- System thread pool [active=0, idle=8, qSize=0]
```

GC Log:

```
2022-02-17T19:01:05.911+0000: 378554.327: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young), 0.0196024 secs]
   [Eden: 3678.0M(3678.0M)->0.0B(3678.0M) Survivors: 8192.0K->8192.0K Heap: 3994.3M(6144.0M)->317.1M(6144.0M)]
 [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]
```

Can anyone please suggest on what could be the reasons for high jvm long pause.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this documentation](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/perf-troubleshooting-guide/memory-tuning). It might also happen in case of VM freeze for a backup procedure, a JVM safepoint or so.

Comment: Hi Alexandr, thanks for the response , but if there are any issues in  JVM processing side, then that time will get added gc time right?